# need help on drop down css menu (messy indent)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

im trying to make css drop down menus : http://jsfiddle.net/zaesegaff/fjC3U/

```
    <ul id="nav2" class="sf-menu">
<li class='current_page_item'><a href='index.php'>HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href='?content=matkul'>SUB MENU 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='?content=matkul&id=1'>Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='?content=matkul&id=2'>Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='?content=matkul&id=3'>Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='?content=matkul&id=4'>Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='?content=matkul&id=5'>Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='?logout'>LOGOUT</a></li></ul>
```

css:

```
/* NAVIGATION ------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    background-color:#000;
}
#nav-holder{
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top:68px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#nav2{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family:"bebas Neue";
}

#nav2 li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#nav2 li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#nav2 li a{
    color: #f0efeb;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav2>li>a:hover,
#nav2>li.current_page_item>a{
    color: #d24c0a;
    background: url(../img/sprites.png) no-repeat center -51px;
}       

/* sub nav */
#nav2 li ul{
    padding:0px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    display:none;
}
#nav2 li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    padding:3px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    z-index:2000;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
    color: #d24c0a;
}

#nav li ul li{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
}

#nav2 li ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

#nav2 li ul li{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #939392;
}

/* text nya */
#nav2 li ul li:hover{ 
    background: #4e4e50;
    background-size:contain;
}

#nav2 li ul li:hover a{ color: #fff; }
```

but my question is:
1. how to make that become like this:

- Sub Menu

  - Menu 1
  - Menu 2
  - Menu 3
  - Menu 4
  - Menu 5

On my code, it messy, and also it has different margin (or padding?) on first child menu

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fjC3U/3/

I cleared a bit your css, as said previously the float was the main issue, plus some confusions on position settings :

```
/* NAVIGATION ------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    background-color:#000;
}
#nav2{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family:"bebas Neue";
}

#nav2 li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position:relative;
}

#nav2 li a{
    color: #f0efeb;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav2>li>a:hover,
#nav2>li.current_page_item>a{
    color: #d24c0a;
    background: url(../img/sprites.png) no-repeat center -51px;
}       

/* sub nav */
#nav2 li ul{
    padding:0px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    display:none;
}
#nav2 li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    z-index:2000;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
    color: #d24c0a;
}

#nav2 li ul:hover
{
    display: block;
}

#nav2 li ul li{
    display: block;
    float:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #939392;
}

#nav2 li ul li:hover
{
   background-color:red;
}

#nav2 li ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get them flowing down, you have to add a `clear:both` to the second list as you have a `float:left` inherited.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjC3U/1/

Comment: im sorry, but it did not answer my question. my question is why my code has different indent on sub menu? and why it does not auto <enter> on sub menus?

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
#nav2 li ul
{
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please care to add some explanation to your single-line-stretched-to-three-lines answer?

Comment: @ Ashiwini..according to me..yes its answer as i read lines and i gave ans..and evn i wrote that add this means simple add this in css..i tried to upload jfiddle bt sorry m new so i dont knw how to add so sorry for that..bt i tried frm myself..and i think thats right

Comment: @Rachcha..as per i have seen the qus..user wants his answer and i tried this and it was working so  i said add this in your css..and same i tried to add jsfiddle but i cudnt so i said in that way..sorry if it looks odd..

Answer (score 0):

To align the sub-menu items one below the other you have to make few css changes.

```
#nav2 li ul li{
  float:none; //to remove the float: left assigned to #nav2 li
}
```

Change

```
#nav2 li:first-child{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

to this so that the `padding-left:0` will be applied only to the first li item of the main menu

```
#nav2 > ul li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/B4EXC/)

To make further changes to the sub-menu list items, add the styles to this `#nav2 li ul li`. For eg to add a border bottom to the sub-menu li item

```
#nav2 li ul li{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
}
```